# Shopify - Adding Image to Notification Emails

Tags: email, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to add images of products that a customer has bought to the Order Confirmed email notification. I currently am using this as my attempt:

`<img src="{{ line.line_item | img_url: 'small' }}">`

I tried that based on [this page](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/url-filters#img_url). I also tried the following:

`{{ item.product.featured_image |  product_img_url | img_tag }}`

Neither way worked. All I'm getting back is a placeholder image that says "no image" on it. This leads me to believe that my syntax is correct, but Shopify can't find the image I'm looking for. I set an image for the product in the admin page, and to make sure I have a big image and a smaller one, as well as set an image on the variant (although there is only the default, one variant for this product). None of it is working. Does anyone have any experience in this and can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot add product images to emails. http://docs.shopify.com/manual/settings/notifications/email-variables

Comment: In the default code for some of the emails, they included the above syntax and are the ones that gave me the idea of it. Thus, although it is not listed specifically on that page, I believe it can be used. Not by a specific attribute of `line_items` but by using the `img_filter` in some way.

Comment: Here's an excerpt right from the default notification:         `<ul style="list-style-type:none">`
  `{% for line in fulfillment.fulfillment_line_items %}<li>`
    `<img src="{{ line.line_item | img_url: 'small' }}" />`
    `{{ line.quantity }}x {{ line.line_item.title }}`
  `</li>{% endfor %}`
`</ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of a coworker, we got this figured out. When looping through the `line_items`, do the following to get the image: `<img src="{{ line.product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'thumb' }}">` and the image will output. There are a lot of different image sizes you can use in place of `'thumb'`. [Check those out here](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/url-filters#size-parameters).

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

The default Order Confirmation email template uses the [`img_url`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/url-filters#img_url) filter:

```html
{% for line in line_items %}
  <li>
    <img src="{{ line | img_url: 'small' }}" /> 
    {{ line.quantity }}x {{ line.title }} for {{ line.price | money }} each
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This is preferable to using `line.product.featured_image` because it will display the line item's variant image if one exists.

From the [Shopify docs for `img_url`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/url-filters#img_url):

> For `line_item`, the URL of the line item's variant image is returned. If the variant does not have an assigned image, the URL of the product's featured image is returned.

Alternatively, you could replace `<img src="{{ line | img_url: 'small' }}" />` with any of these options that use the [`img_tag`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/html-filters#img_tag) filter:

```html
{{ line | img_url: 'small' | img_tag }} // my preferred option

{{ line | img_tag }} // default size is 'small'

{{ line | img_tag: 'alt text', 'class1', 'thumb' }} // thumbnail image with alt text and CSS class
```

Comment: I tried just doing `line | img_url: 'small'` and got a Liquid error. The only thing I could get to work was doing the `line.product.featured_img`.

Comment: If it's within the for loop `{% for line in line_items %}` it should work fine. That code is in the default Order Confirmation template, and I also tested it myself. What error did you get?